# Mapbox: getting ANR after some minutes being idle

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

i'm using mapbox sdk version 9.0.0 and mapbox annotation plugin version 0.8.0 in my app.
i'm getting an anr after about 10 minutes from starting the app, since i'm not doing any process in background I think that it's because of mapbox sdk.
from the first second of running the app I get lots of logs like `setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 39 (39) 524 152` in the console and it seems like after the number in the parentheses turns to zero the `setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 524 522` app stops reponding

these are my log before anr :

```
setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 39 (39) 524 152
setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 40 (40) 524 148
setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 524 522

D/Mbgl-HttpRequest: [HTTP] Request with response = 304: Not Modified
I/ri.zomatosampl:        
Thread[3,tid=21084,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xed95dc00,peer=0x15ec3e38,"Signal 
Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
I/ri.zomatosampl: Wrote stack traces to '[tombstoned]'
D/Mbgl-HttpRequest: [HTTP] Request with response = 304: Not Modified
D/Mbgl-HttpRequest: [HTTP] Request with response = 304: Not Modified
```

any solutions?

Comment: Is this issue reproducible or in any way correlated to a visual change in the map? That is, perhaps a certain dragging or clicking gesture results in the ANR (though perhaps not, since you did mention the issue occurs after being idle). The `setVertexArray` method might be more relevant here, which is specific to Flutter rather than Mapbox. Also worth noting that the 304 Not Modified probably has to do with tile requests and caching after a certain amount of time on the client side by the SDK.

Comment: @AdrianaBabakanian I'm using mapbox in a fragment, I was calling mapView.onDestroy() in onDestroy method, it seems that after replacing it  a calling it from onDestroyView the problem is sloved.

Comment: Glad to hear the problem is solved!

Comment: @MohsenEinhesari Just verifying your fix for this. You moved the mapView.onDestroy() to the fragment's onDestroyView()? Do you still get the setVertexArrayObject messages in your log, or does this just prevent the app from eventually crashing?

Comment: @user3479586 yes I moved the mapView.onDestroy() to the fragment's onDestroyView() and it fixed the crash. I don't have access to the source code to check about the log messages but I think I was still getting them, but no more crashes.